# How to handle a meteor app that uses local mongodb database when offline and syncs to remote mongodb server when online?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need help with how to implement a solution for a challenge I am currently facing with developing our app.

The app is made using meteor and has a desktop version made using meteor-desktop. Everything works perfectly if the PC the app is installed is online, but it is in our requirement to have an offline version working (just like how you can still access your emails in microsoft outlook even if it is offline).

The ideal scenario is for the meteor app to use the remote mongodb server when the PC is connected to the internet, then would switch to use the local mongodb which is installed in the PC when it goes offline. Then the data which was stored in the local database should all be synced to the database in the remote server when it goes online and vice-versa.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution for offline support in Meteor would be [`frozeman:persistent-minimongo2`](https://atmospherejs.com/frozeman/persistent-minimongo2)which is an [Atmosphere.js](https://atmospherejs.com) package. It will store your objects in localstorage. Notice there is a storage limitation up to 4.8MB for `persistent-minimongo2`. Another option which is more commonly used for offline support across Meteor's community is [`ground:db`](https://atmospherejs.com/ground/db) It is a bit more complex to use compared to `frozeman:persistent-minimongo2` but it provides better flexibility. There are also more resources in Internet about `ground:db`. For example, you can refer to the Meteor's Forum [page](https://forums.meteor.com/) about it.